# How to filter domain within ajaxStart() of jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I was fetch html from different domain but some function don't work because it use ajax for some task for that domain.

So I want to filter domain before ajax was called.

thanks, advance

**UPDATE:**

I found ajaxPrefilter() http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/

```
Handle custom Ajax options or modify existing options 
before each request is sent and before they are processed by $.ajax()
```

It solved my problem, cheer!! ^^

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `crossDomain: true`. From the jQuery API Docs:

> If you wish to force a crossDomain request (such as JSONP) on the same domain, set the value of crossDomain to true. This allows, for example, server-side redirection to another domain.

**Script**

```
$.ajax({
   url: a_cross_domain_url,
   crossDomain: true
});
```

Comment: thank you for quick reply, @Sathyesh , but can I extract domain from global ajax event like ajaxStart ?

Comment: Yes, you can. Check out the API.